# How to load webform results using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: database, webforms

I have a [webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) and I need to read its results/submissions using **EntityFieldQuery**.

I need to load all the results of a specific webform having a field value. ( load all the submissions of webform node where age = 25 )

Can EntityFieldQuery do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Webform results aren't entities, so you can't use an `EntityFieldQuery`.

You'll need standard db queries to get that data.