# How efficient is views_get_view_result?

Tags: 8, views

I am not a fan of writing long SQL queries and I am a huge fan of Views. When I need a list of nodes, for example for processing nodes in a cron task, I create a view and use `views_get_view_result()` to get the items and process them.

In Drupal 7, I think `views_get_view_result()` returned the node ID and other fields. In Drupal 8, it seems to be also including the fully loaded node object. Although this is very handy, as in most cases I am likely going to need the node object. Is this very memory efficient? Is passing hundreds or thousands of fully loaded node objects not going to cause memory issues?

Is there a way to only get node IDs and then let me use them to call `Node::load()`?

Comment: If you switch the View to display fields and add only the Node ID field you'll only get node IDs in the result. It's an opinion-based thing, but before I start to write lengthy queries I really like this method as well. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/295322/15055

Comment: Thanks @leymannx. When my colleague had first set this up he was doing content format rather than fields; so I thought the reason. But I switched to fields and still passes full entities. I'll try the code you referenced in the morning.

Comment: Tried it again just to be sure and nope, using fields makes no difference; the full entities are passed regardless. Using the Views::getView() function is the same thing and also returns full entities. views_get_view_result() is just a wrapper for Views::getView()

Comment: You can always entity queries (I guess you already know that) But drupal wraps sql nicely, as far as entities go, and I think it is always the best solution for commands etc.

Comment: Ah interesting! I'd still consider that at least a loadMultiple have loaded the nodes then, so it's probably not much to worry about. But let's see if other answers are incoming.