# How to query webform submissions table

Tags: webforms

I have a webform which contains a field of visit_date, and 3 fields of time selection visit_time_1,visit_time_2 and visit_time_3 which at least one must be filled and they cannot have same time with each other.

Upon submission I want to check whether another user has already submitted the same visit_date and the same time of visit in any of the visit_time_1,visit_time_2 and visit_time_3 fields in case they are not null (e.g. I need to know whether visit_time_1=visit_time_2 etc).

For this reason I query the webform_submission_data which has the EAV model, therefore I tried to implement the solution found [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230576/entity-query-field-condition-for-webform-submissions/267306#267306). The query I have so far is this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT sid
 FROM webform_submission_data wsd
 WHERE wsd.webform_id = 'book_visit_form'
 AND sid IN (SELECT sid FROM webform_submission_data wsd2                   
              WHERE wsd2.value = '2022-10-20'
                AND wsd2.name = 'visit_date')
 AND (
  sid IN (SELECT sid FROM webform_submission_data wsd3
              WHERE wsd3.value IN ('15:00:00','16:00:00','17:00:00')
                AND wsd3.name = 'visit_time_1')
 OR sid IN (SELECT sid FROM webform_submission_data wsd4
              WHERE wsd4.value IN ('15:00:00','16:00:00','17:00:00')
                AND wsd4.name = 'visit_time_2')
 OR sid IN (SELECT sid FROM webform_submission_data wsd5
              WHERE wsd5.value IN ('15:00:00','16:00:00','17:00:00')
                AND wsd5.name = 'visit_time_3')       
 )    
                ;
```

So my question is whether my logic is correct or should I change something in my query in order to get the desired results.

Comment: Does the query produce the desired results?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entity Query field condition for Webform submissions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/230576/entity-query-field-condition-for-webform-submissions)

Comment: @cilefen I m getting some results when I shouldnt e.g. when some of my values are nulled. So basically I think I have some errors in my query logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably reduce the three OR'd queries into one by using `AND wsd3.name LIKE 'visit_time_%'`

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestion. Does this cover the possibility of the nulled values? Because I dont want to return results if for example the user has filled one time slot with an hour which has not been selected before and the others are empty

Comment: Yes it should exclude null values because of the IN clause